# Capture bash function's result and allow it to exit

Tags: bash, shell-script, trap

This function should exit the calling script:

```bsh
crash() {
  echo error
  exit 1
}
```

This works as expected:

```bsh
echo before
crash
echo after         # execution never reaches here
```

But this does not:

```bsh
echo before
x=$(crash)         # nothing is printed, and execution continues
echo after         # this is printed
```

How do I capture the result of a function, as well as allow it to exit?

Comment: Find info about `trap`.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Thanks good idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `$(crash)` executes `crash` in a subshell, so the `exit` applies to the subshell and not to your script.

What is the point of capturing the output in a variable if you won't use it because the script exited anyway?

Comment: Sometimes I want to return something, OR if something bad happens, to exit. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
echo before
x=$(crash) || exit       # if crash give -gt 0 value then exit with the same value
echo after
```

Comment: `exit` (without $?) will exit with the value of the last command executed

Comment: While this may solve the OP’s problem, it doesn’t, strictly speaking, answer the question. This will exit if the function does ``return 1`` and not if it does `exit 0`.